# php route - how I can display good image path

Tags: php

I am using PHP and trying to display an image in a view. Here is the code that displays the image.

```
if ($annonce->avatar)
            $res .= '<a href="../src/'.$annonce->avatar.'" alt="avatar" class="img-thumbnail">Lien</a>';
```

In **src folder** I have

- avatar folder

image.png ^

- controller folder
- entity folder

^ Actual file where I am and where the code is executed but the path is not correct How I can display it please ?

---

In template folder I have:

1. annonce

^ index.php The file in question who call entity functions

2. home
3. favoris

EDIT: the image is not displayed, even with the img tag

```
$res .= '<img src="'.dirname(__DIR__).'\avatar\\'.$annonce->avatar.'" alt="avatar">Lien</img>';
```

Comment: First: you should change <a href="..." with <img src="...". Second: could also be a path problem. Did you try to check what $annonce->avatar contains? It should be avatar/image.png.

Comment: third: Image exists physically and is not of size 0? fourth: you sure index.php under annonce is used? Maybe it is included/required somewhere else. Edit: You switched slashes. Why? Please try to open your image in the browser via domain/src/avatar/image.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer your question as I understood you, because I miss some vital info about your system. But I think you have some problems understanding routing in php and the browser.

Folder structure:

```
root/website_x/
- src/
  - avatar/
    - image.png
  - controller/
  - entity/
  - ...
- template/
  - annonce/
     - index.php
     - ...
  - home/
  - favoris/
  - ...
- index.php
- index.html
- ...
```

I guess you have this url:
`localhost/website_x/index.php`

If you have a real server and a domain, your path would be like: `www.website-x.com`

Truth is, [www.website-x.com](http://www.website-x.com) points at `root/website_x/index.php`.

1. the browser handles a path different than the server (php)
2. the template/annonce/index.php is not used directly. It is included via magic of the website.

When it come to using files in the browser, you have to think like the browser. If you browser opens the url [www.website-x.com](http://www.website-x.com), than the root is where the server tells  him where it is. In our example, it is [www.website-x.com/(index.php)](http://www.website-x.com/(index.php)). The browser does not know the folderstructure of the server.

So the fact is, if you place an `<img src="../src/avatar/image.png">` the browser cant find it because it looks there `www.website-x.com/../src/avatar/image.png` what is mostly wrong. Thats why I told you to open the image in the browser via url. But [www.website-x.com/src/avatar/image.png](http://www.website-x.com/src/avatar/image.png) should display your image in the browser. Or localhost/website_x/src/avatar/image.png if you use xampp.

###### What you can do with php to tell the browser the correct path:

Your $annonce->avatar variable should contain the path beginning from the root of the website. Means `localhost/website_x/src/avatar/image.png` or `www.website-x.com/src/avatar/image.png`. The path `src/avatar/image.png` or even `/src/avatar/image.png` can (and possibly will) cause other trouble.

###### Other things which could prevent your browser from displaying your image, even with a correct path:

- htaccess forbids that
- webserver does not have the rights to access the image
- image file is corrupt

Comment: Thank's for replied and the clarity of your explanation +1

Comment: Don't mention it. Hope it helped.

Answer (score 0):

To display an image, you should not use the `<a href="SRC_IMG"></a>` tag but the `<img src="IMG_SRC">` tag...

Comment: this is not the question .. and the problem is same

Comment: You can use absolute path instead of relative path. using the function [`realpath(string $path)`](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.realpath.php).